# parametrization of $(2 \times 2)$ special unitary group

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory

[image]

Here $G$ is a $(2\times2)$ special unitary group. How is this parametrization possible? I tried to calculate from the definition of the group but it does not seem to work well. Could anyone provide me with some efficient way?

Comment: What do you mean, "How is it possible"? Do you mean, which is the set of all such $U$ equal to $\textrm{SU}(2)$? In any case this characterization does not define a parameterization, as the quantities $z_1, z_2$ in which $U$ is expressed satisfy an implicit equation.

Comment: I just want to solve the exercise I uploaded. I tried to calculate from the definition, but like you said, I only get implicit equations. So, my calculations do not seem to work well.

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you indicate exactly what happened when you "tried to calculate from the definition".

Answer (score 0):

What this says is that if
$$U=\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$$
is unitary and $ad-bc=1$, then $c=-\overline b$, $d=\overline a$ and $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$.
The rows of $U$ form an orthonormal basis. So $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$
and $(c,d)=\lambda(-\overline b,\overline a)$ for some $\lambda$,
as these are the vectors orthogonal to $(a,b)$. From the determinant
being $1$ we get $\lambda=1$.